# Reading text following the matched string in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I'm reading the values from the command prompt output and entering the values read from command prompt in the excel. is there a way to read the values following the matching string.
For example, in ping,

```
Pinging 10.140.79.20 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.140.79.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.140.79.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.140.79.20: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.140.79.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
```

in the above output of ping, is there a way to read the TTL values by reading values after "TTL=" string using vbscript ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to cut a part from a string. In your case, using Split() on "=" seems to be an easy strategy:

```
>> s = "Reply from 10.140.79.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255"
>> t = CInt(Split(s, "=")(2))
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(t), t
>>
Integer 255
>>
```

If you need more parts of the linput line, a RegExp gives you more bang for a bit more buck:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "\d+"
>> Set ms = r.Execute(s)
>> WScript.Echo ms(0).Value, ms(4).Value, ms(6).Value
>>
10 32 255
>>
```

**Update wrt Stephan's comment:**

Touché. For some (special) cases the Split() approach may still be used:

```
>> s = "Reply from 10.140.79.20: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255"
>> a = Split(s, "=")
>> t = CInt(a(UBound(a)))
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(t), t
>>
Integer 255
```

but then it looks like too much buck for not enough bang.

Comment: nice idea, but: there are lines with `time<1ms` and lines with `time=1ms`, so split on `=` will give unreliable results

Comment: i am not using the ping in my case, output of my command looks like this: initial time: 5.00003ms , final time: 5.99044ms.. so should i use "inital time" itself as the delimiter?

Comment: @Shashank - please update your question with *real* sample data. As my blunder proves, *careful* analysis of the input data is necessary to come up with a suitable approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can just search for `TTL`. Then read 4 chars after that up till the end of the line.

```
intPos = InStrRev(s, "TTL", -1, vbTextCompare)

If intPos > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo Mid(s, intPos + Len("TTL="))
End If
```

If your output looks like `initial time: 5.00003ms , final time: 5.99044ms`, just replace `"TTL"` with `"final time:"` in the code above.

You could also split *on* `"final time:"`, in which case the 2nd array element will be what you need.

```
' Split and return what comes after 'final time:' in one step...
strTime = Split(s, "final time:", -1, vbTextCompare)(1)
```